# How can I write a launchd service that will actually stop the service?

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

So I have a plist to keep monit running:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.monit.service</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/Cellar/monit/5.10/bin/monit</string>
        <string>-d 60</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/monit.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can do `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.monit.service.plist` to start the service, but `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.monit.service.plist` will not stop it. I can see that the process keeps running no matter what I do.

The process shows up like this(note how the binary path doesn't show up, only the last argument):

output of ps aux:

```
root            14656   0.0  0.0  2482248   1656   ??  S     6:55PM   0:00.09 -d 60
```

How can I write the launchd plist so that it will actually stop the freaking process whenever I want it to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `-d 60` arguments and use the `launchd` key `StartInterval` instead. Also make sure the process does not daemonize itself. According to the `monit` man page this is accomplished by using the `-I` option.

Comment: For the record, my monitrc file only had this:`set daemon 60` and I needed this: `set init set daemon 60`. So essentially, I was daemonizing monit.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect since it is running from `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`  and not the user `~/Library/LaunchAgents` you need to use `sudo` to issue the command with permission.

`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.monit.service.plist`

Comment: I'm running these commands as root, so I don't think that's the issue.